# Reading files from a csv file with python showing the first list and not displaying appended files in the correct order

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, data-analysis

I am new to python, please kindly help out. I saved data into a CSV file in python and I am trying to read the data from another file but the result retrieved is the first on the list. all other appended files aren't reading in the correct order. what I think is that it is reading the space between the two generated files as an empty list.

```
result=[]

for my_campaigns in campaigns:
.....
result.append(my_campaigns)

with open('data.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    csv_writer.writerow(result)
```

the data is in this format

```
 "name{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }","
"name{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }","
 "name{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }"

"appended{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }","
"appended{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }","
"appended{
""key"": 3179.0,
""key1"": ""23844801202540758"",
""key2"": ""June 16 - June 27 PH"",
""key3"": ""2020-06-21"",
""key4"": ""2020-06-25"",
""key5"": ""18226"",
""key6"": ""3179.37""
 }"
```

the code I used in retrieving from file is

```
 data_read=[]
 with open('data.csv', newline='') as csv_file:
     csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
     for read in csv_reader:
         data_read.append(read)
 print(data_read)
```

it returns all odd elements in the list: data_read[1], data_read[3] as an empty array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are empty lists being added because of your 'newline' choice.
Your file effectively had a data structure of

item\n
\n
item\n
\n

This means that for the gaps where you have no item, but a new line, the reader assumes there must be a (blank) item there.

Perhaps the easiest solution would be to use '\n\n' as your newline delimiter, or write the data in such a way as to remove the gaps.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I will try that now